# Why do Windows 7 basic theme (no-aero) render all UI on CPU?

Tags: windows, user-interface

I see lots of people say that the Windows Aero offload the UI to GPU thus make it's actually faster than Windows Basic theme, so I did a compare test and verified it's true, the Basic theme is more lag and use much more CPU when doing the same thing(such as fast moving a window continuously).

So why don't Basic UI run on GPU? Wouldn't a simple UI with GPU offload be the best thing? Also I want to know how the UI is handled in a System with no Aero, such as Windows XP or Windows 10?

Comment: At least in Vista the whole point of the "basic" theme was to be less graphically demanding for systems with little or no built-in graphics ability. It limited itself to 2D graphics and did not use the more demanding 3D desktop compositing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU rendering of the UI was first introduced with Windows Vista. Before that there was only CPU rendering on Windows (and most other systems). Basic acts as a fallback and I guess the engineers assigned to implement GPU rendering for the UI hand no time budget left or it was simply out of scope to implement ways to make GPU rendering work for the Basic theme.

This changed a bit with Windows 8(?) or 10 where you get desktop composition effects you could only get with Aero and GPU rendering before which was a surprise to virtual machine users who knew that 3D capabilities were disabled. This is the opposite of what you were suggesting (a simple UI rendered on the GPU).

Utilizing GPU acceleration can be very complex because you need hardware, driver and software to all support a particular feature set of a protocol which wasn't as widely available as it is today. Remember we're talking about code written about a decade ago.